# Spark: How to salt and evenly spread data across executors without aggregation?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

How can I salt and roughly evenly spread my data across the executors?

What I have tried:

```
n = 2000
train = train.withColumn("salt", (F.rand() * n).cast(IntegerType()))
train = train.repartition(n, "salt")

# also
train = train.repartition('salt', 'y')
```

Each is giving me the same answer as if I had not ran these operations with 500m rows sitting on a single executor when I go to write the files to disk. `y` is my heavily skewed column.

Most examples of salting incorporate aggregation, but I have no needed aggregation.

Comment: Sure -- but surely azure databricks is identical to GCP and AWS however, right?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly: You want to evenly spread your data across the executors and speed up the process of writing files to disk? If so and if you don't care how the data is written to different files, why don't you just use `.repartition(n)` with declaring the `numPartitions` only but not the `cols`?